# iCal file for Google Calendar with guests getting email reminders

Tags: email, google-calendar-api, icalendar, reminders

I'd like to set up a script to produce weekly event ICS files that include guests and reminders for them a few days in advance.  I created an event in Google Calendar and tried to copy what it produced, but it didn't work.  Here's what I tried:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Urbina//Personal//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20151011T160000Z
DTEND:20151011T170000Z
DTSTAMP:20151006T172727Z
ORGANIZER;CN=Me Dude:mailto:urbancenturion@gmail.com
UID:urbancenturion@yahoo.com0005
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;CN=urbancenturion@hotmail.com;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:urbancenturion@hotmail.com
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;CN=urbancenturion@yahoo.com;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:urbancenturion@yahoo.com
LOCATION:Kaos
SUMMARY:event led by two people
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

There may even be a problem with the line breaks, but they won't render properly in the code window--since I clearly don't know what I'm doing here (new-ish guy).

Edit:
Oops, right and right.
What I wanted was for the two people to be indicated as guests and for there to be a reminder e-mail sent to them 4 or 5 days before the event.  (I would produce the event files for each week, all at the same time, months in advance, and import them so I don't have to manually enter them each week.) The event is created, but the 'guests' don't appear.  I am assuming the e-mails won't be sent either in that case.

Comment: You are missing the leading BEGIN:VCALENDAR but this is probably just a copy/paste typo (?). But more importantly, you are not specifying *what* did not work.

Comment: ...crickets... ...no love... ...tears... etc.

Answer (score 2):

Before BEGIN:VEVENT you need to have METHOD:REQUEST